# DrawerLayout or Constraintlayout should be a parent view?

Tags: android

I want to add DraweLayout to the MainActivity layout, but has no idea what the parent view should be? DrawerLayout or Constraintlayout?

First option:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Second option:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which option is correct?

Comment: Use FlexBox for your entire Layout...Its much better than any of the normal layouts available and easy to change https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: DrawerLayout should be parent.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. Hope this helps you too

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

           <!-- your content here -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```